# Transfer transparency from one image to another using imagemagick

Tags: images, imagemagick, transparency

I am trying to take the alpha channel from one image and apply it to another.

In this particular case I want to "fix" the corners on the pink one. I want to use the alpha channel from the black one. This should smooth out the corners nicely.

[image: source-1] [image: alpha-1]

[image: source-corner] [image: alpha-corner]

I have tried commands like `convert pink.png black.png -compose copy-opacity -composite out.png` but it only seems to come out with the same transparency it already had.

Can anyone please explain how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Direct Answer**

To make it so that `pink.png` has the same alpha channel as `black.png` use:

```
convert pink.png black.png -compose CopyOpacity -composite PNG32:fixed.png
```

**Explanation**

The fundamental problem was that Imagemagick was not choosing a PNG format that supports semi-transparent pixels. This is why my edges became jagged when I was changing the colour in the first place. You have various options to maintain the partial transparency:

```
convert (command) PNG32:out.png
convert (command) PNG64:out.png
convert (command) out.tif
```

Refer to Imagemagick's [documentation on PNG sub-formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#png_formats) to find out what type of alpha channel each has.